# Fetch failed: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have multiple modules defined in IntelliJ pointing to different Git repositories. When I do a pull on the entire project IntelliJ says

> "Fetch failed: Could not read from remote repository"

How do determine which is the problem repository without pulling from each one individually?

Comment: Make sure your root project dir have a valid remote url ..
$git remote -v
Verify with this command

Answer (score 0):

Check the Console tab of the Version Control toolwindow - it shows all the git command prefixed with the git root name in `[]`. Find the command that fails and check the prefix.